# advantages of hashing over elliptic curve signatures for a proof of work protocol

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, signature

I'm trying to create a proof-of-work protocol for a proof-of-concept software, and it's basically something like this:

```
privkey = that user's private key
pubkey = that user's private key
```

both are ECC

```
message = "some message"
difficulty = advertised difficulty

log2 (sign(privkey, hash(pubkey+"|"+message+"|"+difficulty+"|"+hard_worked_nonce))) < difficulty
```

This means that the signature must begin with a specific number of zeroes, as advertised in the message; else the message is discarded as spam.

The user must compute a had_worked_nonce which will render the condition above as true.

Is it any reason why i couldn't skip hashing and only do this? I plan on using ed25519.

```
log2 (sign(privkey, pubkey+"|"+message+"|"+difficulty+"|"+hard_worked_nonce)) <= difficulty
```

Comment: It might work fine in practice, but I would probably not trust it.  Elliptic curve points are easily distinguishable from random strings (unless you work very carefully specifically toward that purpose http://cr.yp.to/elligator/elligator-20130527.pdf).  My intuition is that it wouldn't work terribly, but why risk it when you could very simply, and at little cost, use a hash, which is designed to be pseudorandom.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread it the first time.  If your signature algorithm had the properties that you wanted it to have, then I don't think the hash would be necessary (besides the fact that it reduces the amount you have to sign over).  However, as I said before, it probably does not.  Ideally, the log2 should be applied to the hash inside the signature, because the signatures are not actually random and would not suffice for a proof of work.

Comment: signatures are not actually random? my impression is that they disperse over 0 -> 2 ** exp pretty well.

Comment: @poncho you are right, i miss-typed.

Comment: Nowhere in the definition of a secure signature does it specify that it is or even should be pseudorandom.  For instance, you can take any secure signature algorithm $S(x,k)$ and create an equally secure algorithm $S'(x,k) = S(x,k) \| 0^{100}$.  $S'$ is now highly non-random, but still a secure signature.  In particular, elliptic curve points, when translated into binary strings, are easily distinguishable from uniformly random strings (see the article I linked above).

Comment: It does not matter for me if the keys are recognized as ecc public keys. I need the signature to be as random as possible when small modifications occur, and by doing a simple check, they seem to spread out quite evenly on 0 -> 2 ** exp. :/
I'm not sure if you are familiar with proof-of-work schemes. I really need to figure out if i lose security by not hashing the string.

Comment: As I said before, no, you don't lose anything by not doing the hash inside.  Most implementations of signing functions will do a hash anyway though, so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  As I said before, there is concrete evidence that elliptic curve points (i.e. your signatures) are distinguishable from random.  You might have done a "simple check" but that is not acceptable cryptographic evidence.  What reason do you have for not using a standard hash-based proof of work anyway?

Comment: Just code performance, but this question is something i have asked myself for a long time. Signing a piece of data is as good as hashing it (for some specific tasks)..